# Errors in NDSolve for complex matrices

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, numerical-integration, complex, quaternions

This is the problem. It is quite simple, and looks unwieldy only because I had to rewrite quaternions as complex matrices.

```
Io={{1,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,2}}
NDSolve[{{{I ω1[t],ω2[t]+I ω3[t]},{-ω2[t]+I ω3[t],-I ω1[t]}}==2ConjugateTranspose[{{Λ1[t],Λ2[t]},{Λ3[t],Λ4[t]}}].{{Λ1'[t],Λ2'[t]},{Λ3'[t],Λ4'[t]}},{{P1[t],P2[t]},{P3[t],P4[t]}}=={{0,I},{I,0}}.ConjugateTranspose[{{Λ1[t],Λ2[t]},{Λ3[t],Λ4[t]}}].{{I,0},{0,-I}}.{{Λ1[t],Λ2[t]},{Λ3[t],Λ4[t]}},Io.{ω1'[t],ω2'[t],ω3'[t]}+Cross[{ω1[t],ω2[t],ω3[t]},Io.{ω1[t],ω2[t],ω3[t]}]==Re[P1[t]]{Im[P1[t]],Re[P2[t]],Im[P2[t]]},Λ1[0]==1,Λ2[0]==0,Λ3[0]==0,Λ4[0]==1,Λ1'[0]==0,Λ2'[0]==1/2,Λ3'[0]==-1/2,Λ4'[0]==0,{ω1[0],ω2[0],ω3[0]}=={0,1,0},{ω1'[0],ω2'[0],ω3'[0]}=={0,0,0},P1[0]==0,P2[0]==1,P3[0]==-1,P4[0]==0,P1'[0]==-1,P2'[0]==0,P3'[0]==0,P4'[0]==-1},{Λ1,Λ2,Λ3,Λ4},{t,0,1},DependentVariables->{Λ1,Λ2,Λ3,Λ4,Element[ω1,Reals],Element[ω2,Reals],Element[ω3,Reals],P1,P2,P3,P4},Method->{"DAEInitialization"->{"Collocation","CollocationDirection"->"Forward"}}]
```

Mathematica says:

```
NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function ω1 appears with no arguments.
NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function ω2 appears with no arguments.
NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function ω3 appears with no arguments.
NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

The ω's only appear without arguments inside Element[]. So I have some questions.

1) Isn't `DependentVariables->{Element[f, Reals]}` the standard way to tell that f should be real-valued? Why the error?

2) Why IDA? Is it the only method available for solving DAEs?

3) Do I absolutely have to rewrite quaternions to real-valued matrices? That is possible, but would be absolutely unwieldy (a 4*4 matrix for one quaternion, and quaternion literals appear eight times). And it would not guarantee success.